# SSRS. How to hide blank/empty column via expression?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-expression

I need to hide column if all rows in column is empty (blank).

In this case `col3` should be hidden, because no values in column.

```
col1 col2 col3
 v1   v4
 v2
 v3
```

I'm using following expression on columns `Hidden` property:

`=IIF(Fields!Test5.Value = "",TRUE,FALSE)`

This expression working, but It hidding each blank(empty) field, even all column isn't empty. It should hide column only when there is no values at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

`=IIF(Max(Field, Dataset)= "",TRUE,FALSE)`

If the maximum value is empty it means that there is nothing, and make your hide expression on column.

Comment: Please reference directly to dataset, ie:
=Max(Fields!InvoiceID.Value, "SalesInvoiceDS")
We are referencing to the "whole" dataset values, not current tablix context

Comment: @sdrzymala this is great. Thanks a lot! I just want to mention that if you want to hide the column use the Visibility field and not the Hidden one.This way, when the column is empty, no gap will be present. So, in case of a tablix, right click on the column, choose Column Visibility and write down the above expression below "Show  or hide based on an expression".

Answer (score 4):

in case of an SSRS report, right click on the column and click **Textbox Properties**, choose **Column Visibility** and write down the below expression on *"Show or hide based on an expression"*

You can use below if the column value is  Null:

```
=IsNothing(Fields!Column.Value)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question of hiding if *all* values in the column are empty. At best, if it works at all, this will silently get the *first* value (implied `First()`) and wrongly hide based on that.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked

```
= IIF(Max(Fields!Test5.Value)= "",TRUE,FALSE)
```

Notice that I have not added Dataset name in here.

Comment: Note that this is *exactly* the code that OP already tried.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me - combination of CountDistinct aggregate function and check that the first value is Nothing.

Example of the condition for a column visibility:

```
=iif(
      (
        CountDistinct
                     (
                      Fields!Settlement_Manager.Value, "dsDetails"
                    ) = 1 
                   Or CountDistinct
                                  (
                                   Fields!Settlement_Manager.Value,     
                                   "dsDetails"
                                  ) = 0
                   ) 
                 AND IsNothing
                             (first
                                   (
                                    Fields!Settlement_Manager.Value, 
                                    "dsDetails"
                                   )
                            ), true, false
                    )
```